# SAS 9.3 goptions ignores gsfname

Tags: sas, gchart

Sorry for my bad english :)

I need to export gif picture from SAS proc gchart:

```
filename graphout "&PATH.\file.gif";
goptions gsfname=graphout dev=gif gsfmode=replace;
    proc gchart data=work.temp;
        /*forming chart*/
    run;
quit;
filename graphout clear;
```

But export occurs in the work directory. What's the problem?

Comment: I didn't notice a problem either... perhaps the macro `&PATH.` is not resolving correctly and it is not finding the file path.

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out what the problem is with the option, but I recommend not using that to create your graphics in any event.  ODS is much easier to use.  There are a lot of ways to do this in ODS; the HTML destination is usually the easiest:

```
ods html gpath="c:\temp\" path="c:\temp\";
   proc gchart data=sashelp.class;
        vbar age/group=sex name="mychart";
    run;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem with you. After I tried to put

```
ods listing;
```

before your code, it works.